# RestSharp.RestResponse instead of json string as Authentication Response

Tags: c#, json, authentication, webforms, restsharp

I have been working on using a Rest Api for authentication (https://api.vorexlogin.com/)
So far I have added the RestSharp library to dismiss errors to RestClient and RestRequest.

So far when I run the code that I have in the textbox I get this:

```
   RestSharp.Response
```

The Response that is needed should be something like:

```
"success": true,
"result": {
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGtccccc.xxxx.yyyyzzzzz",
    "refreshToken": "67ZYfdsJFDKLS879337937DKJSDLGFSDFRDEMO=",
    "accessTokenExpireOn": "2021-07-03T22:19:23.8330686Z",
    "refreshTokenExpireOn": "2021-08-02T21:49:23.8330686Z"
}
```

Even if it failed it should still be a json file of some sort. I will provide my code below.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.vorexlogin.com/v2/security/authenticate");
        var request = new RestRequest("resources", Method.Post);

        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "grantType=password&userName=+"+ usernametbx + "&password=" + passwordtbx + "&tenant=" + tenanttbx, ParameterType.RequestBody);



        var response = await client.PostAsync<IRestResponse>(request);
        textBox1.Text = response.ToString();
    }

    public class IRestRepsonseList
    {
        public string accessToken { get; set; }
        public string refreshToken { get; set; }
        public string accessTokenExpireOn { get; set; }
        public string refreshTokenExpireOn { get; set; }
       

    }
    public class IRestResponse
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public List<IRestRepsonseList> result { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `PostAsync<T>` you tell RestSharp to deserialize the response to `T`.  Your `IRestResponse` class doesn't implement `ToString()`, so the default `object.ToString` is used by your code, which just returns the instance class name.

I cloud also suggest you read the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#get-or-post), as you wrote lots of unnecessary code.

Here is an example of what you should be doing:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.vorexlogin.com/v2/security/authenticate");
var request = new RestRequest("resources", Method.Post)
    .AddParameter("grantType", "password")
    .AddParameter("userName", usernametbx)
    .AddParameter("password", passwordtbx)
    .AddParameter("tenant", tenanttbx);
var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
textBox1.Text = response.Content;
```